# Python Regular expression matching tuple pairs

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Looking for a regular expression to match tuple pairs within a list. Have been using the below regular expression

```
s = '[(aleakedteaserand, NN), (abehind, IN), (the, DT)]'    
re.findall(r'\((.*,.*)\)',s)
```

but it still missing the end braces.

```
['aleakedteaserand, NN), (abehind, IN), (the, DT']
```

Expected output:

> [(aleakedteaserand, NN), (abehind, IN), (the, DT)]

Comment: Put proper quote marks in the expected output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't make the RegEx ungreedy. The solution is `re.findall(r'\((.*?,.*?)\)',s)`.

Comment: To get the expected output as mentioned in the question, move the escaped `(` to the inside of parenthesis: `re.findall(r'(\(.*?,.*?\))', s)`.

Comment: @Wray. No. OP wants to match but not capture parens.

Comment: @Wray. The brackets and parentheses in the expected output are the list of tuples findall returns in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives. First one uses a complement match often used as an alternative to non-greedy search where it is not available.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\(([^)]*)\)',s)
['aleakedteaserand, NN', 'abehind, IN', 'the, DT']

>>> re.split('\), \(', s.strip('[()]'))
['aleakedteaserand, NN', 'abehind, IN', 'the, DT']
```

No regex

```
>>> s.strip('[()]').split('), (')
['aleakedteaserand, NN', 'abehind, IN', 'the, DT']
```